# Explain the logic of dealing with objects in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

Look at the following code:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            word word = words.get(position);

            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FamilyActivity.this, word.getAudioResourceId());
            mMediaPlayer.start();

            //*************Releasing resources
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
        }
    });
}
```

It belongs to a Listview.
When a row in that ListView is clicked, this method intercepts the click and plays the corresponding song for that item.

In the fourth line you see this code: `word word = words.get(position);`

- What is "position"?
- And what is the ".get()" method?
- And can we save them in a word object?

Would you explain this specific line of code, please?

---

PS: For more detail I'm gonna show you the "word" class and also "words" ArrayList in case you needed to see it:

```
public class word {

//////Atributes
private String mDefaultTranslation;
private String mMiwokTranslation;
private int mImageResourceId=NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
private static final int NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED=-1;
private int mAudioResourceId;

//Constructor
public word(String defaultTranslation,String miwokTranslation,int audioResourceId){
    mDefaultTranslation=defaultTranslation;
    mMiwokTranslation=miwokTranslation;
    mAudioResourceId=audioResourceId;
}
public word(String defaultTranslation,String miwokTranslation,int ImageResourceId,int audioResourceId){
    mDefaultTranslation=defaultTranslation;
    mMiwokTranslation=miwokTranslation;
    mImageResourceId=ImageResourceId;
    mAudioResourceId=audioResourceId;

}

//Getters
public String getDefaultTranslation(){
    return mDefaultTranslation;
}
public String getMiwokTranslation(){
    return mMiwokTranslation;
}
public int getImageResourceId(){return mImageResourceId;}
public boolean hasImage(){return mImageResourceId != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;}
public int getAudioResourceId(){return mAudioResourceId;}
```

and this is "words" arraylist:

```
 final ArrayList<word> words = new ArrayList<word>();
    words.add(new word("father", "әpә", R.drawable.family_father, R.raw.family_father));
    words.add(new word("mother", "әṭa", R.drawable.family_mother, R.raw.family_mother));
    words.add(new word("son", "angsi", R.drawable.family_son, R.raw.family_son));
    words.add(new word("daughter", "tune", R.drawable.family_daughter, R.raw.family_daughter));
    words.add(new word("older brother", "taachi", R.drawable.family_older_brother, R.raw.family_older_brother));
    words.add(new word("younger brother", "chalitti", R.drawable.family_younger_brother, R.raw.family_younger_brother));
    words.add(new word("older sister", "teṭe", R.drawable.family_younger_sister, R.raw.family_older_sister));
    words.add(new word("ounger sister", "kolliti", R.drawable.family_younger_sister, R.raw.family_younger_sister));
    words.add(new word("grandmother", "ama", R.drawable.family_grandmother, R.raw.family_grandmother));
    words.add(new word("grandfather", "paapa", R.drawable.family_grandfather, R.raw.family_grandfather));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not meant to be a [Google](http://www.google.com) replacement. Nor a place where to ask for programming lessons or tutorials.

Comment: @Rotwang Ok.I figured it out,I'm sorry.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is "position"?

Indirect answer - Think about the purpose of the click listener. What are you clicking on - an item. It needs to know **which** Item you clicked. Hence, `position`

> And what is ".get()" method?

this seems to be answered yourself. `words` is an Arraylist. How do you "get" an item out of an Arraylist?

In either case, the JavaDoc could answer both of those questions

> can we save them in a word object?

What is "them"? You *are* getting an instance of a `word` object, the variable name also happens to be `word`, though.

Save the position? I wouldn't recommend that. What good would storing the position of the word in one list when that same object could be in another list, at some different position?

Comment: about the last part,so why did we used an "equal sign" to a "word" object?

Comment: You said **in** a word object. That is not what that line of code is doing. It is only getting a word object **out** of the list

Comment: This part:"word word =".Explain this part a little more.storing the position in an object?how?

Comment: The first `word`is a reference type (the class name), for the second `word` which is simply the variable name and can be named anything else. Basically, you should be able to answer yourself how does `int x = 0;` work and apply that to any other variable assignment. If not, I suggest you please learn more about Java and how variables work.

Comment: I think you may be confused that class names should start with a capital letter, always.

Comment: I think in your example x is a primitive data type and not a class.I think we can deal with classes with by their methods and you can not say for example: myDearClass objectDamnName =0;

Comment: maybe you should say myDearClass objectDamnName.set(0)

Comment: Cursing isn't necessary, but again, class names should be capitalized. If myDearClass extended the Integer class, you can do the former, but we've gotten off topic

Comment: Really?myDearClass objectDamnName =0 has no problem?sorry for the cursing thing, I didn't mean it.I got 2 downvote.thats the reason I felt confusing.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the Integer class will perform auto-boxing. With regards to the downvotes - "Question contains no research effort". As I and some other answers have addressed, both your questions are answered if you take the time to find the method references in the Android API documentation. (Which would probably have been faster than posting on StackOverflow)

Comment: Alright, then. Feel free to accept any answer you wish

Answer (score 0):

"Position" is the position of list item being clicked. Like if you clicked "mother" item... position will be 1, it starts from 0.

.get(position) is the method of ArrayList.. which returns the specific item of arraylist depending on position.

Yes, you can save word object like this.

Answer (score 0):

**words** is ArrayList, which is associated with ListView, so when onItemClicked is called, you take **position** of item in ListView. So, If you want to get specific object, which is associated with ListView item on **position**, you call **get**() method of ArrayList. You now have **word** object, which is associated with list item at **position** position.

Answer (score 0):

Position is the index in the array of views in the adapter of the item you are clicking on. the get() method just returns that view from the array.

You can reference parts of the view and save their values as Strings, Objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`word` is a reference type. The ArrayList words contains references to several word objects. 
`words.get(position)` returns a reference to the word object in the ArrayList at that index, starting from 0.
`word word = words.get(position)` takes a reference to the word at position in the ArrayList `words` and assigns it to `word`, so that `word` now 'points' to the object in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
word word = words.get(position);
```

"position" refers to the position in the list that was clicked. You can see it is passed into the function as an int parameter:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

The get() method is most likely Java's List get method here, which returns the item in the list at the given index:
[Java List javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int))

To put them together, this line is saying "give me the 'word' object from the ArrayList 'words' that was clicked on, based on the int 'position' "

**NOTE**: One other coding note, it is common practice to name classes with a beginning capital letter like "Word" instead of "word". This will avoid confusion between what is a class and what is a variable.